# Overwrite FPDF output

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using fpdf in php to generate a pdf and output it to a directory.

```
$pdf->Output("/home/file/path/uploads/"."test_pdf.pdf", "F");
```

If there is already a file at this location called test_pdf.pdf, will fpdf overwrite it? If not, how can I make it?

Comment: Have you tried running it and seeing what happens?

Comment: I agree with @Andrew Fan, testing is usually the best option.  Unless of course the question is "If I run this DELETE command in SQL, will all the records disappear"? In answer to your question, yes, if the filename is the same, it will overwrite it.  If you don't want it to, and just want something random to save it as, use something like [microtime].pdf as your output and that will pretty much guarantee no conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) and [source code](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/master/fpdf.php#L980)  your parameters are in the wrong order:

```
string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
```

```
function Output($dest='', $name='', $isUTF8=false)
```

The [implementation](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/master/fpdf.php#L1019) is as simple as this:

```
case 'F':
    // Save to local file
    if(!file_put_contents($name,$this->buffer))
        $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
    break;
```

Last but least, [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents) without `$flags` parameter (emphasis mine):

> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, **the existing file is overwritten**, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

I can't blame you if you aren't willing to do this research—you can always just try the code and see what happens :)